# Can't change data in Firebase Realtime Database when using Cloud Functions

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I want to reset a specific value in my Firebase Realtime Database every day at 12:00 AM. I'm using Firebase Cloud Functions to do this. This is the code that I have:

```
exports.dailyReset = functions.pubsub.schedule('0 0 * * *').onRun((context) => {
  exports.resetValue = functions.database.ref('/users/{userId}')
      .onWrite((change, context) => {
        var ref = change.data.ref;
        ref.update({
            "daily": 0
        });
        return ref.update({"daily": 0});
      });
  return null;
});
```

Upon testing the script, it doesn't work. It's not resetting the value in my Firebase Realtime Database. Can someone tell me how do I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible to use the Functions SDK to write to the database.  `functions` can only be used to establish triggers that run when the triggering event occurs.

In other words, `functions.database.ref('/users/{userId}').onWrite()` isn't going to write anything at all.

If you want to write to Realtime Database from a nodejs program, you should use the [Firebase Admin SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup) to [write data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/admin/save-data).

Comment: Does that mean I can't use the schedule functions? I need that before writing to the database.

Comment: You can use the Functions SDK to schedule a function for execution - the triggering event in that case is time.  But you have to use the Admin SDK to read and write data with Realtime Database.

Comment: I've updated my code. Is this the correct way to approach it?

Comment: If you have new code, you really should ask a new question that explains the issue.  Stack Overflow is not effective when the question keeps changing over time.  When the question changes, that invalidates all the answers on that question.  If you have a new question about the use of the Admin SDK in Cloud Functions, that is definitely a new question.

Comment: Isn't the question still relatively the same? Same purpose as before.

Comment: No.  Before you were trying to use the functions SDK something it was never going to be able to do.  Now, you've completely changed the code, and it seems you are trying to use the Admin SDK as I suggested, but doing it incorrectly.  Frank also seems to agree.  I am going to revert the question back to its original form, and I suggest that you ask the new question separately.

Answer (score 1):

The Cloud Functions triggers in your `index.js` file have to be known and fixed when run `firebase deploy`. That means you can't dynamically create triggers from inside a Cloud Functions, as you're trying to do.

The common approaches for dynamic scheduling are:

1. Have a single Cloud Function that runs periodically and then executes the tasks for the past time period.
2. Dynamically schedule Cloud Functions with Cloud Tasks, as Doug describes in his blog post [How to schedule a Cloud Function to run in the future with Cloud Tasks (to build a Firestore document TTL)](https://medium.com/firebase-developers/how-to-schedule-a-cloud-function-to-run-in-the-future-in-order-to-build-a-firestore-document-ttl-754f9bf3214a).

But in your case, why do you even need the `onWrite` trigger? Can't you just [import the Admin SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/get-started#import-the-required-modules-and-initialize-an-app), user that to read all users, and then delete them?

Comment: I've updated my code using the Admin SDK. Is this the correct way to approach it?

Comment: Please don't change your question in a way so that the existing answers (largely) don't make sense anymore, as it means the question is of no value to future visitors. If my (or Doug's) answer makes sense and explains why your approach doesn't work and how to move forward, you should upvote/accept them. If you have problems implementing the approach, open a new question for the new problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
const { onSchedule } = require("firebase-functions/v2/scheduler");
const { logger } = require("firebase-functions");
const admin = require("firebase-admin");
admin.initializeApp();

exports.updatePoints = onSchedule("every day 17:30", async (event) => {
  await admin.database().ref("USERDATA/").once("value")
    .then(function(snapshot) {
      const users = snapshot.val();
      logger.log(users);
    });
}
```

Use `await`, so its working for me I'm using visual studio code, windows 11, nodejs